# It it safe to do this in php?

Tags: php, html

I am new to php, and I want to know if it is safe to do it like this...
I currently have a login system to protect a few pages.

1. Is it possible for a hacker to change the value of $logged_in?
2. Is this safe?
3. If it isn't. what is the best way to do it?

Files:
 - not_logged_in.php
 - test.php
 - login.php
 - logout.php
 - protected_page_1
 - protected_page_2
 - unprotected_page_1

Code:

not_logged_in.php:

```
<html>
    You are not logged in!
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php

$logged_in = false;

function protect_page() {
    if($logged_in == false) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}


?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php

include "test.php";
$logged_in = true;

?>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php

include "test.php";
$logged_in = false;

?>
```

protected_page_1.php:

```
<?php

include "test.php";
protect_page();


?>


<html>

    Content

</html>
```

protected_page_2:

```
<?php

include "test.php";
protect_page();


?>


<html>

    Content

</html>
```

unprotected_page_1:

```
<html>

    Content

</html>
```

I completely understand that the login.php page just logs in and you don't have to give in a password, but that is just for testing currently...

Thanks for reading!

Comment: in test.php:  the variable `$logged_in` does not exsist within the function. It is not in the function's scope

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier Oh, I only see that now... Thanks!! How can I change that, becouse somewhere I need to set the veriable $logged_in to false, and I dont know where.

Comment: G'day, though it's not actually a bad question, it's clear that you're very much starting to learn PHP. If you don't mind, I would suggest you do some courses to gather a basic understanding, [such as this](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php) and [maybe this](https://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/). Where as this is a Q&A site, there you might get the additional information that would leave you understanding the "why" to most of the questions you'll run into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way of using this $logged_in variable is too loose.

I suggest to make use of sessions.

session.php:

```
<?php
session_start();  // start on top of your page before any output

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
}

function loggedin()
{
   return $_SESSION['loggedin'];
}

?>
```

and in any page with protected content.

```
<?php
    include 'session.php';

    if(!logged_in()) {
       include 'login.php';
       exit();
    }
    // some info
?>
```

login.php will have a form to log in. (and to `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;`
every page could include session.php.

Comment: This is working! but is there a way to remove the session when someone closes my site? Because if I close and open my site it is still logged in.

Comment: sessions work with cookies. at the first contact, the server will give the browser a cookie with a value of some long random string. Every time the browser contacts the server, it will present the cookie along with the request. You can setup your browser so it will keep that string even after closing. However after some idle time (often 20 minutes) the server it self will forget that value. So if the browser comes after 30 minutes with that old cookie, the server will not recognize him

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's protected. Maybe you can store the variable that shows weather the user is logged or not in a session storage to make it even more efficient.

Comment: as test.php contains a function with a missing var, that var evals to null. So you are never logged in. The page will be very well protected and can never be seen...

Comment: @IvoP Oh, I only see that now... Thanks!! lol, How can I change that, because somewhere I need to set the variable $logged_in to false, and I don't know where.